# How to check if argument is defined in function definition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example if I have a function defined like this:

```
function set_name(name) {
    return name;
}
```

But I call it this way (for personal reasons this way):

```
set_name.apply(this, ['Duvdevan', 'Omerowitz']);
```

What would be the best practice to check and prevent `set_name` function's further execution if it had accepted more than `1` parameter / argument?

Also, I have to note that I'm trying to figure out a way to check this before I call `.apply` function:

```
function set_name(name) {
    // if(arguments.length > 1) console.log('This is not what I need though.');

    return name;
}

var args = ['Duvdevan', 'Omerowitz'];

// Now, at this point I'd like to check if the set_name function can accept two arguments.
// If not, I'd console.log or return new Error here.

set_name.apply(this, args);
```

Is this doable?

Comment: So if it has more than one argument, you want it to not run? Only way would be the if like you coded it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number of arguments expected by the function via [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

```js
function set_name(name) {
  return name;
}

var args = ['Duvdevan', 'Omerowitz'];

console.log(set_name.length);         // 1

if (args.length > set_name.length) {
  throw new Error('Too many values'); // throws
}

set_name.apply(this, args);           // not executed
```

Comment: Pretty damn awesome! Actually, I was afraid that I'd have to do `set_name.toString()` and parse the actually function definition for defined arguments ... but this, you're a JavaScript Gandalf! Thanks!